# How to make the sidebar transition?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a simple splitview that has a rectangle of width 4px that indicates the selected item in the spiltview.

```
<Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                           Width="4" Height="48" Margin="1,0"
                           Fill="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}" Grid.Row="2"
                           Visibility="{x:Bind btnHome.IsChecked, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Right now I've multiple rectangles turned on/off depending whether the checkbox is selected or not! But instead, I want a single rectangle in my code that should transition from the place where it previously was to place where the user has clicked.

[image: SPlitView Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest for you would be using the new [`NavigationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) if your minimum version is set to Fall Creators Update or use the [`HamburgerMenu` control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/controls/hamburgermenu) from UWP Community Toolkit (note that it's updated to use style very similar to yours, the docs aren't just updated with current screenshots). You can download the UWP Community Toolkit Sample App from Windows Store if you want to see how it currently looks.

If you want to use your custom solution, you should create a custom style or rather edit an existing style of the control you're using as hamburger menu items. Default styles are available for example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299122.aspx).

Comment: Wait a sec, Fall creators update hasn't been released! Are you referring to insider previews?

Comment: Yeah, `NavigationView` is available only in insider preview and will not run on older versions of windows 10. So it will probably be better to use the `HamburgerMenu` control from UWP Community Toolkit.

Comment: Can I somehow achieve that without using HamburgerMenu? With some logics! I would prefer to go that way.

Comment: As I said, you'll have to edit the template of the control you're using.